# TSQL Large Update in Batches - Is Join Costing Me More Because it is Performed Each Time in a Loop

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to archive many records in batches rather than in one shot.

Will TSQL Join the two tables, TeamRoster and @teamIdsToDelete for every loop in the batch? My concern is that if my temporary table is huge and I don't remove records from the temporary table as I go, the JOIN might be unnecessarily expensive. On the other hand, how expensive is it to delete from the temporary table as I go? Is it made up for by the (?real/hypothetical?) smaller joins I'll have to do in each batch?

(Can provide more details/thoughts but will do so if helpful.)

```
DECLARE @teamIdsToDelete Table
    (
        RosterID int PRIMARY KEY
    )   

--collect the list of active teamIds. we will rely on the modified date to age them out.
INSERT INTO @teamIdsToDelete
SELECT  DISTINCT tr.RosterID FROM 
        rosterload.TeamRoster tr WITH (NOLOCK)
            WHERE tr.IsArchive=0 and tr.Loaded=1 


--ageout out remaining rosters. (no cap - proved we can update more than 50k by modifying test case:
WHILE (1 = 1)
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRANSACTION

    UPDATE TOP (1000) r
    SET [Status] = 'Delete', IsArchive = 1, ModifiedDate = GETDATE(), ModifiedBy = 'abc'
    FROM rosterload.TeamRoster r with(rowlock)
    JOIN @teamIdsToDelete ttd ON ttd.rosterID = r.RosterID
    WHERE  r.[Status] != 'Delete' AND r.IsArchive != 1 AND r.ModifiedBy != 'abc' -- predicate for filtering;

    IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0 -- terminating condition;
        BEGIN
        COMMIT TRANSACTION
        BREAK
        END

    COMMIT TRANSACTION
END
```

Comment: of course it will repeat the join - that's exactly what you are telling it to do!

Comment: yea, it would look that that on its face, but I don't know much about the query execution engine and what happens in the background. it seems that often, things like this are optimized. even if not, is it more expensive to do a bigger join? maybe the operation is constant?

Comment: a single statement is optimized, not so much with a loop.  All in all, you will make the db do less total work if you ditch the "batch" operation and do one big update. Otherwise, you are repeating some (maybe a lot) of the overhead with each batch.  Utilize **execution plans** to see just how much work the db is doing.

Comment: I wonder about this too - ditching the batch completely. Especially I wonder whether it's a bunch of developers not understanding relational dbs well enough to think that batches are a good idea. I see that it will be less work, but what about other concerns, such as the large table gets locked or hung up and nothing is deleted.

Comment: Good point - if concurrency is the bottleneck, then you may be better off doing it in batches. Doing it in "chunks" absolutely will always require the same or greater amount of work (usually greater), but trading some extra I/O's for something that doesn't hold locks for a long time may well be worth it.

Comment: Thanks. Ok. So, if we assume that batch update is acceptable - should I be deleting from my temporary table as I update? So as to minimize subsequent joins.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125735/discussion-between-slimsghost-and-jacoblambert).

Answer (score 1):

As I understand the goal of this query is to archive huge number of rows w/o blocking other queries at the same time. The temp table helps you to narrow down the subset of records to delete. Since it has one column which is clustered primary key, the join to another PK will be blazingly fast. You will spend more efforts on calculating and deleting updated records from the temp table.

Also, there is no reason to use transaction and do batches. You could just do one big update instead. The result is the same - table will be locked after first 5k row locks are acquired (~after first five batches updated) until the COMMIT statement. With rowlock hint does not prevent lock escalation. On the other hand, running w/o transaction would give other queries opportunity to continue after each 1000-row batch. If you need to make sure that all records are archived in one go - add some retry logic to your query or your application code for such errors like deadlocks or process interruption. And do you really need NOLOCK hint?